# Foundation Orbit custom thumbnails not changing main image

Tags: thumbnails, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm using the Foundation framework and Orbit. I've built the slider here: http://www.abricot-production-dev.co.uk/group-two/gallery.html#
but the thumbs are not changing the main pics at the moment.

My code:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="images/slider/image-01.jpg" data-thumb="image-01.jpg" data-caption="#captionOne"/>
    <img src="images/slider/image-02.jpg" data-thumb="image-02.jpg" data-caption="#captionTwo"/>
    <img src="images/slider/image-03.jpg" data-thumb="image-03.jpg" data-caption="#captionThree"/>
</div>

<span class="orbit-caption" id="captionOne">Here is another caption...</span> 
<span class="orbit-caption" id="captionTwo">Here is a caption 2...</span> 
<span class="orbit-caption" id="captionThree">And here is a caption 3...</span>

<ul class="orbit-bullets">
    <li class="has-thumb" style="background-image: url(images/slider/thumbs/image-01.jpg); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; ">1</li>
    <li class="has-thumb" style="background-image: url(images/slider/thumbs/image-02.jpg); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; ">2</li>
    <li class="has-thumb" style="background-image: url(images/slider/thumbs/image-03.jpg); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; ">3</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Initialised:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
       $("#slider").orbit();
   });
</script>
```

And in foundation.min.js:

```
bullets:!1, bulletThumbs:!0, bulletThumbLocation:"../images/slider/thumbs/"
```

What am I missing?

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

Implementation:

```
<ul class="disc">
  <li class="has-thumb" style="background-image: url(images/slider/thumbs/image-01.jpg); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; "data-orbit-link="headline-1">1</li>
  <li class="has-thumb" style="background-image: url(images/slider/thumbs/image-02.jpg); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; " data-orbit-link="headline-2">2</li>
  <li class="has-thumb" style="background-image: url(images/slider/thumbs/image-03.jpg); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; " data-orbit-link="headline-3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it works.

Cheers.

Comment: This might be out-of-date. I could not find any of the implementation text on the linked page.